# Posting data from Ionic app to WordPress

Tags: api, rest-api

Does anyone know? How can I post the blog post from ionic app to a WordPress back-end? My idea is to make a list of blog posts from ionic app (user will post data from app and create a post).

Thank you for everything!!!

Comment: Have you looked at the REST API? https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: No, looking for an example, I gone through with Rest API but did not get solutions.

Comment: Please take the time to take the [tour] and looking at the [ask] would also help you out

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this my friend is by using the REST API. In you ionic app you will make a post request to the api. You will need to go through Oauth for authentication and so forth, but that's what the REST api is made for.

Comment: I have tried with rest api and Getting an Error [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 1081ms] {"code":"rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.","data":{"status":401}}